How the OAuth 2.1 flow using Mobile-OTP authentication in Spring Security 6.2+ should be?
What I have:
Spring Boot 3.2+
Spring Security
Spring Authorization Server
What I want to achieve:

User login using Mobile and OTP authentication.
Following OAuth 2.1 + PKCE

Questions:

Client applications will hit the oauth2/authorize endpoint with proper header and will be redirected to a custom login page (added in /resources/static). After entering mobile number and otp user will be redirected to redirect_uri of request and then request the oauth2/token with code returned after successful oauth2/authorize request.

I have implemented custom authentication filter which validates OTP and return successful authentication object but I am confused, how would I achieve this flow in Spring? Currently, I am unable to return redirect_uri?code=''.

Am I following correct approach?
No: What am I missing or doing wrong?
Yes: Is there any better practice or approach? Any suggestion or reference?


Security Config:
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private OTPAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    private static final String LOGIN_PAGE_ENDPOINT = "/index.html";
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_ERROR_ENDPOINT = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGOUT_ENDPOINT = "/logout";
    private static final String SUCCESS_ENDPOINT = "/dashboard";

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http
                .exceptionHandling(
                        c -> c.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(LOGIN_ENDPOINT),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain appFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider);

        http
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(otpAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/**","/assets/**",
                                "/api/otp/generate", "/api/otp/verify", "/api/users/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE_ENDPOINT)
                        .permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl(SUCCESS_ENDPOINT)
                        .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(LOGIN_ERROR_ENDPOINT))
                )
                .logout(
                        form -> form.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGOUT_ENDPOINT))
                                .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_ENDPOINT + "?logout")
                                .permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public OTPAuthenticationFilter otpAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new OTPAuthenticationFilter(LOGIN_ENDPOINT, authenticationManager());
    }

}

Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks!
EDIT
May 17th:

Based on recent debugging, I found the possible issue could be with the way I implemented AuthenticationProvider.
After /login POST request, it should return to OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider but it doesn't, therefore it is unable to redirect to requested redirect_uri

